# What are the applications in which the precision of the neural network's weights is unimportant?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, pytorch, implementation, weights

While reading about [Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) in PyTorch, I came across a new data type called `half` datatype.

`half()` method when calls on a Module casts all floating-point parameters and buffers to **half datatype**.

It is a 16-bit floating-point number as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).

It is mentioned in Wikipedia that

> It is intended for storage of floating-point values in **applications
> where higher precision is not essential** for performing arithmetic
> computations.

It implies that the precision of parameters (say, weights for a neural network) is not important in certain applications and hence one can use half datatype while implementing a neural network.

Did any research support the statement that **precision, that is the range of values it takes, of weights, is unimportant** for certain applications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, research into ultra-low precision neural network is generally referred to as network quantization. For example, the weights and actications of an artificial neural network can be quantized down to 4-bit, or in extreme cases even 2-bit and 1-bit (binary neural networks).

This is a good introductory article to start with:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08295, which goes into detail how network quantization can be done to the maximum extent of preserving the original network accuracy.

The applications of network quantization is immediate. A network with lower precisions would use much less memory and compute power, which is particularly important on edge devices.

However, I do not know whether there are certain ML tasks that are more amenable to quantizatios then others. Generally speaking, we talk about quantization on a network basis. For example, if you quantization ResNet-50, you can generally use this network to run multiple CV tasks like classification, detection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a tradeoff allowing you to fit a larger model into a fixed RAM budget (ie the size of your GPU). Whether this is a good tradeoff is model- and data-specific, but anecdotally I’ve had good luck with it and usually use half precision to good effect (NLP, mostly).

Comment: Please make a note of the change in the question.